# printing array in a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have the following code:

```
 I=0;
 L=0;
for i=1:20

   m=[I;L];
   hold on
   plot(1:20,m(1:2),'*');

   I=I+1;
   L=5+I;
end
```

The purpose of this code is in the beggining of each one of the 20 iterations, the table m, to change the values. after this part i want to print the I,L with different plot in the same figure.After that there is code which change again the values of I,L,M. The result i want to be a plot for each one of the I,L.But i don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to have a plot with all the data overlaid on top of each other, and a plot for each individual set of data?

Comment: i want to have two different plots.one for the values of I and one for the values of L. the yaxis it will be the values (of I and L) and the xaxis it will be 1:20. for example the value of I in the first iteration is 100, so my point is (1,100) the next point (2,110) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
 I_value=0;
 L_value=0;
 I = [];
 L = [];
 for i=1:20
     I_value = I_value + 1;
     L=[5,I];
     I=[I,I_value+1];
 end

 figure;
 plot([I;L]','*');
```